# Video editing not showing video preview

Tags: video-sequence-editor

This problem just occurred, whereas yesterday is was working perfectly fine. I didn't change anything, just logged onto blender and now I can't see my preview? None of the other answers have helped me so far.

EDIT: Blender files
[image]

[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: Check the edit is that good?

Comment: maybe you've changed the files folder?

Comment: I don't believe I did, like I said everything was the same and then this morning it just didn't show

Comment: Try to select all strips and in the Strip menu select Unmute.

Comment: Maybe the timeline playhead is in the wrong frame? The playhead should stay within the frame range of all the strips otherwise there's nothing to show.